Paste and enter insert mode at the beginning of line, terminal bash Lunarvim
When editing a text file, p and I pastes what I copied and gets me to enter insert mode at the beginning of line.
But in terminal (executed by term bash) this not works.
p pastes somthing, but I or i enters insert mode at the end of line instead of the beginning.
How to get I works like in text file?

In Terminal mode Vim let the terminal manage the way input are managed. That is why hitting I merely switch from Normal mode to Terminal mode moves the cursor at the end of the line.
You could add the following mapping to mimic the behavior:
nnoremap <expr> I &bt≈='terminal' ? "I\<Home>" : 'I'

For the terminal buffer it maps I to I Home
